# Names appearing twice in list view items

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listfragment

I'm trying to set up a 2-line list view but each string seems to copy itself within the item rather than showing it once. How can I prevent this from happening? i.e. I need the data to appear like this: for Item 1 - America, America Description rather than America, America; for Item 2 - Europe, Europe Description rather than Europe, Europe. See screenshot for evidence of the undesired result.

**ListData.java**

```
public class ListData {

    public static final int[][] items = {
            {R.string.america,R.string.america_description},
            {R.string.europe, R.string.europe_description}
    };

}
```

**ListViewAdapter**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<String> mData;
    private List<String> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<String> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = data;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String strItem = mFilteredData.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.mDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTitle.setText(strItem);
        holder.mDescription.setText(strItem);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;
        private TextView mDescription;
    } 
}
```

**item_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/item_title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ItemListadapter.java**

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<String> mData;
    private List<String> mFilteredData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;

    public ItemListAdapter (List<String> data, Context context) {
        mData = data;
        mFilteredData = data;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFilteredData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mFilteredData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String strItem = mFilteredData.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            holder.mDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.mTitle.setText(strItem);
        holder.mDescription.setText(strItem);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    /**
     * View holder
     */
    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;
        private TextView mDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Filter for filtering list items
     */
    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {

        /**
         * Invoked on a background thread.  This is where all the filter logic should go
         * @param constraint the constraint to filter on
         * @return the resulting list after applying the constraint
         */
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                results.count = mData.size();
                results.values = mData;
            } else {
                //Create a new list to filter on
                List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String str : mData) {
                    if (str.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        resultList.add(str);
                    }
                }
                results.count = resultList.size();
                results.values = resultList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        /**
         * Runs on ui thread
         * @param constraint the constraint used for the result
         * @param results the results to display
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            } else {
                mFilteredData = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add how to you call the constructor of the ItemListAdapter

Comment: Use a Model class which holds title and description, and change your adapter to make it use this model class

Comment: I think you have to change the type of object for the list of objects that you pass to the list adapter (an object which holds both the name and description of data).

Comment: It's a nice widget. For simple use cases I would still use the ListView though

Comment: @Blackbelt, agreed. I initially intended to stick with the ListView.

Comment: I think you should accept @fondessa answer. Take a look to the documentation and to the example In the sdk and if you have issues, simply ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is shown two times in `ListView` because you are passing in both `TextView` the same item:

```
String strItem = mFilteredData.get(position);
```

To avoid this and use two separate fields you need to pass to your adapter a model with two field:

```
public class CustomListItem {
    private String title;
    private String description;

    //get method

    public CustomListItem(String title, String description){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Then you have to add them to create a `new List<CustomListItem>` in your activity/fragment that use the adapter and pass to the adapter this list:

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomListItem>{
    private Context context;
    private List<CustomListItem> data;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<CustomListItem> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MacaronLover Yes, because i suppose that you have to use it also in your fragment/activity

Comment: Ok, I've just create **CustomListItem.java** and have added the CustomListItem code you suggested. Now for **ItemListAdapter.java**, just to clarify, would I need to use `extends ArrayAdapter<CustomListItem>` instead of `extends BaseAdapter`? Also which section(s) of code do I need to remove before adding `private Context context;
    private List<CustomListItem> data;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<CustomListItem> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }`?

Comment: @MacaronLover yes, you have to use it instead of BaseAdapter. For the second question/answer i can recommend you: https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
As you can see here, the correct approach  would be to use a RecyclerView.Adapter